# What are rich pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

I like C++ and follow its development.
While browsing I came across this link:

http://www.cplusplus-soup.com/2012/01/rich-pointers-frequently-asked.html

Can someone explain the concept of rich pointers in simple terms ?

Comment: And this post (epsecially together with the linked proposals) doesn't help at all? Besides that, what is the actual problem you're facing and the specific question you got?

Comment: I don;t think anybody but the author of the paper is able to do so succinctly. You need to contact the author as this is a completely new concept that is being proposed to the standards committee and not something that is currently in the language. Though if somebody does have an answer I would love to read it.

Comment: The blog post in the link doesn't help that much, but the one that's linked there is a little better: http://www.cplusplus-soup.com/2012/01/c-extensions-rich-pointers.html It is still a bit complicated and incomplete though. I think this is a fair question and should stay open. "Not a real question" is not a valid reason to close this ("Explain yield in python to me!" questions get 1k+ upvotes on here!), if there's any then it is that no implementation is currently available.

Comment: @us2012: the difference being that `yield` already exists, while rich-pointers are a possible extension being thought up by the blogger.

Comment: No specification, no implementation. For now a fair summary is "like pointers, but with `%` instead of `*`."

Comment: @Christian, I am not facing any problem as such. This question was curiosity. I was not satisfied by the explanation in the blog link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least as I read it, they're "tagged pointers". In other words, the pointer doesn't just carry the address of the item it points at, but has some associated metadata to tell what sort of thing the pointer is intended to point at.

Comment: I concluded the same, but I feel that I'm missing some important details.  The metadata must go far beyond `typeinfo` to suggest a change to the language itself.  Perhaps it helps facilitate automatic garbage collection?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. +1 *tagged pointers* hint by Jerry. I was trying to related rich pointers to smart pointers. I was completely mistaken. I think the motivation behind rich pointer is different than that of smart pointer.